# Xcode 8 Live preview xib

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode, interface-builder, live-preview

I am trying to create calendar UIView that will look similar on any device. To archieve this I thought why not to use this live preview option in Xcode, but when I add view to IB and set class to MyCalendar live preview does not render anything. I tried simple things like setting background color in xib and this color does not appear, but when I add simple UIView without any class and set color, live preview works for this view.

To be specific I have 3 xib files. 1 for main collectionView 1 for collectionView header and 1 for cell.

When I am in cell or header xib live preview works, but I need to inspect collection view and how it will work after cell will be added. Is this possible using live preview?

Comment: Do you mean live rendering?
If that what you wants is to make your custom view customizable from the Storyboard, then this video may be helpful.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bToFQRIPeGo

Comment: Your link refers to using custom class on view, but I need to know how to load and live render xib.